# Scroll inside scroll is not working

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a table with class `poptable` inside a div with class `popBody`.I applied `overflow-y:auto;` for the div.It works fine.

I have another table with class `tblcheckbox` inside one tr of table with class `poptable`.I also applied

```
overflow:auto;
position:absolute;
```

for the table.The scroll works fine. but when I scroll the div  with class `popBody` ,the table with class `tblcheckbox`  not scrolled due to the css   `position:absolute;`.
See the issue here [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nn7WF/) by scrolling the div. I want both scrolls. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `position: absolute` and add `display: inline-block` for this element.

Check this update: http://jsfiddle.net/nn7WF/2/

Answer (score 1):

change in your css

```
#Ingredients {
    display: block;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative;` to the `.poptable` `class`.

It does the job as shown in the [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nn7WF/3/)